# What exactly does the disposed flag mean in Dispose(bool)?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, idisposable

As following example implementation i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose there is a flag indicating redundant calls. In examples it is always in last line in Dispose(bool disposing) method. Does it mean that it indicates that everything has been disposed or just simple protect the method execution to be run once?

```
private bool disposed = false; // To detect redundant calls

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this.cache != null)
            {
                this.cache.Dispose();
            }
        }

        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Is that implementation still correct?

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
        disposed = true; 

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this.cache != null)
            {
                this.cache.Dispose();
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: In your second example, if there is an exception inside `this.cache.Dispose()` then `this.dispose == true` which may or may not be desirable. BTW you should prefix all instance member access with `this.` to avoid confusing fields with locals.

Comment: But if it is a desirable case to not care about exception inside `this.cache.Dispose()` then is it not better wrap that line in try catch block with empty catch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> there is a flag indicating redundant calls. In examples it is always in last line in Dispose(bool disposing) method. Does it mean that it indicates that everything has been disposed or just simple protect the method execution to be run once?

There are *two* flags in the pattern: `disposing` and `disposed`.

`disposed` starts false and is set to true as soon as the object is disposed. The purpose of `disposed` is to make `Dispose` *idempotent*. That is: it should always be legal to call `Dispose` twice, and the second time it should do nothing.

The protected `Dispose(bool)` method in the pattern has two callers: the regular `Dispose` method, and the finalizer. The pattern is that `Dispose` calls `Dispose(true)` and the finalizer calls `Dispose(false)` so that the implementation of the method knows whether to use normal rules or finalizer rules for cleaning up.

Comment: But if `this.cache.Dispose()` will throw exception it could be handled in `try catch` to try to 'unblock' the `cache` and call `Dispose` once again. If `disposed` will be set to true at the beginning then calling `Dispose` second time will do nothing.

Comment: @ziomyslaw: It's a bad practice to have a dispose that throws. And if it throws once, why do you think that calling it a second time will make things better?

Comment: So is it ok to set it to true at the begging and don't worry that disposing resources could fail? All examples of the pattern show `disposed = true;` as last instruction - so my understanding was the flag indicates that we disposed everything successfully - so maybe better name would be `isEverythingDisposed`.

Comment: @ziomyslaw: I don't know, is it OK for you?  **What are the consequences to your users of failing while disposing a resource?** You're the person who can answer this question, not me. **Write the code that your users need you to write**.